# PayPal Rest API: How to add or update card to billing agreement api?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using **[PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)** for billing agreement api. I want to add new new card to existing billing agreement.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/

I've check docs and SDK there is not any proper way to update the card in billing agreement.

Your suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated and not compatible with the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), which do not use a billing agreement for anything. There is no server-side SDK for the current Subscriptions API, so any calls need to be done yourself with HTTPS.

Regardless, payers can update their payment methods and change to a different or new card via login to https://www.paypal.com , Profile, My Money, My Preapproved Payments